# Base64 encoding in Delphi UTF8 charset

Tags: delphi, encoding, base64

According to https://www.base64encode.org/ , the encoding value for **ó** is **w7M=** when using *UTF-8* destination character set.
When character set is *ISO-8859-1*, the result is **8w==**

Delphi's functions `TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString('ó')` and `EncdDecd.EncodeString('ó')` are returning the same value, which is **8w==**

Here's where I need your help. Is there any way to get the result **w7M=** in Delphi ? Those functions do not accept any other parameter.

Thank you!

Comment: Convert the text to UTF8 bytes and then base64 encode that. Remember that base64 encodes bytes to text and decodes text to bytes. So every time you see a function named EncodeString you know it's poorly designed and should not be used.

Comment: Can you use `System.NetEncoding.TBase64Encoding`, like `TBase64Encoding.Base64.Encode('ó')`?

Comment: `TBase64Encoding.Base64.Encode('ó')` Returns `w7M=` as @complete_stranger suggested.

Comment: "System does not contain a member named NetEncoding" - I'm using  Delphi XE

Comment: @complete_stranger why would that convert to UTF8?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `TBase64Encoding` encodes a `string` to UTF-8 before then base64-encoding the resulting bytes. `function TBase64Encoding.DoEncode(const Input: string): string; begin Result := DoEncodeBytesToString(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input)); end;`

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to first convert your UTF-16 string to UTF-8 bytes, then convert this UTF-8 byte sequence to MIME/Base64, like this:

```
  USES System.SysUtils, System.NetEncoding, VCL.Dialogs;

  VAR
    UTF8        : TBytes;
    MIME        : STRING;

  BEGIN
    UTF8:=TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('ó');
    MIME:=TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(UTF8);
    ShowMessage(MIME)
  END;
```

You can pack this into a stand-alone function, like this:

```
USES System.SysUtils, System.NetEncoding;

FUNCTION MimeAsUTF8(CONST S : STRING) : STRING;
  BEGIN
    Result:=TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(S))
  END;
```

If you don't have System.NetEncoding, but have Indy, then this should work:

```
USES System.SysUtils, IdGlobal, IdCoderMime;

FUNCTION MimeAsUTF8(CONST S : STRING) : STRING;
  VAR
    UTF8        : TBytes;
    {$IF DECLARED(TIdBytes) AND DECLARED(TIdEncoderMime) }
      IdUTF8    : TIdBytes;
    {$ENDIF }

  BEGIN
    {$IF DECLARED(TEncoding) }
      UTF8:=TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(S);
      {$IF DECLARED(TIdBytes) AND DECLARED(TIdEncoderMime)  }
        SetLength(IdUTF8,LENGTH(UTF8));
        MOVE(POINTER(UTF8)^,POINTER(IdUTF8)^,LENGTH(UTF8));
        Result:=TIdEncoderMime.EncodeBytes(IdUTF8)
      {$ELSEIF DECLARED(TNetEncoding) }
        Result:=TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(UTF8)
      {$ELSE }
        {$MESSAGE FATAL 'You need to USE either System.TNetEncoding or IdGlobal+idCoderMime' }
      {$ENDIF }
    {$ELSE }
      {$MESSAGE FATAL 'You need to USE System.SysUtils }
    {$ENDIF }
  END;
```

The code should auto-adapt to one of two scenarios. If you have IdGlobal (and IdCoderMime) in your USES clause, it will use the Indy routines. Otherwise, it will expect that you have System.NetEncoding in your USES clause. In all cases, you'd need System.SysUtils as well. If you don't have the appropriate UNITs in your USES clause, the code will refuse to compile.

Comment: "System does not contain a member named NetEncoding" - I'm using Delphi XE

Comment: @plionut: Included an Indy-version of the function for your convenience.

Comment: @plionut if you have a limitation to a very old version of Delphi you should state it when asking

Comment: Note that `TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode()` encodes a `string` to UTF-8 before then base64-encoding the resulting bytes

Answer (score 1):

> Delphi's functions TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString('ó') and EncdDecd.EncodeString('ó') are returning the same value, which is 8w==
>
> Those functions do not accept any other parameter.

You must be using a *very old* version of Indy, because `TIdCoderMIME.EncodeString()` does have an optional `AByteEncoding` parameter, and has for a long time.

However, it defaults to Indy's *8-Bit* encoding. You would have to set it to UTF-8 explicitly, eg:

```
TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString('ó', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8)
```